# How to precisely define a function that chooses randomly from a finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions

Let $A = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

I want to define a function that picks with uniform probability an element in $A$, so that $$f(A) = i \in A.$$

[image]

I don't know how to precisely define this mathematical operation.

Sure, I can say: Let $f: A \to A$, $f(A) = i \in A$. But this does not characterize the randomness at all. Is there a common function that do this work for us?

Comment: Such a thing can't be a function. You're looking for a random variable. Or are you asking for a computer program that implements this procedure?

Comment: @Ian as Robert Israel stated, a random variable is a function.

Comment: If $f(A)$ is a random member of $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then it is not correct to say $f:A\to A$.  Rather, one has $f : \mathscr S \to A$ where $\mathscr S = \{  \{1,\ldots,k\} : k \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\} \}$. $\qquad$

Comment: I should say, it can be a function, and in fact it can technically be a function even defined on $A$, but the "randomness" itself is not encoded in the function alone, it has to be encoded in the structure of the probability space.

Comment: @Ian While implementing the function is always easy, especially in the case of uniform picking. I just never seen this function in "math form" before.

Comment: Since the only sets you're allowing in the role of $A$ are those of the form $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, you may as well let $n$ rather than $A$ be the input. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Robert Israel's answer quite corresponds to the question as now phrased, and at the moment I don't have an answer that precisely does so either.  However, I might let $X$ be a random variable that has a continuous uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ (so that its probability of falling into any subinterval is the same for all subintervals of the same length, and thus the probability is just the length of the subinterval) and then let
$$
f(A) = f(\{1,\ldots,n\}) = \left\lfloor nX \right\rfloor
$$
where $\lfloor a\rfloor$ is the integer part of $a$, so that $a = \lfloor a \rfloor + (\text{some number less than 1})$.

Comment: Shouldn't you *not* divide by $n$, as the OP asks for the function to output integer values?

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed.

Comment: @ClementC. : You're quite right; haste makes waste$\,\ldots\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$f$ should be a **random variable**, i.e. a function defined on a probability space, not necessarily on $A$, such that $\mathbb P(f = i) = 1/n$ for each $i$.  You could take the probability space to be $A$ itself, with each member $i$ having probability $1/n$.

Comment: That's a different probability space for each value of $n$ separately. $\qquad$